# How to Update a Column Value Start From Left by Using Only a Few Words MySQL

Tags: mysql

**Table Structure**

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ url                                        ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/name1 ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2  ║ http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/name2 ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 3  ║ http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/name3 ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

So I'm trying to truncate all url prefixes with that path *(ex: http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/)* so that there are names left at the end, like: **name1**, **name2**, **name3**.

I think this query can work fine, but I think it will change all the values in that column.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `url` WHERE LEFT (`url`, 37) = 'http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/'
```

What I want is to just cut off the front of the url-path **leaving the name at the end.**

I tried to use this query but the query got an error start from the `LEFT` after the `SET` query.

```
UPDATE `table` SET LEFT(url, 37) = '' WHERE LEFT(`url`, 37) = 'http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/'
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: There are lots of string functions in MySQL

Comment: Use MySQL [substring](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simplest

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET url = TRIM(LEADING 'http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/' FROM url)
```

If the value starts from the specified substring - it will be trimmed, else the value will not be altered.

Comment: Can i add `where` clause into this query? like `UPDATE table 
SET url = TRIM(LEADING 'http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/' FROM url) WHERE id = 'ID_001'`

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal Of course, nothing prevents. PS. If `url` column is indexed then additional `WHERE url LIKE 'http://example.com/path1/path2/path3/%'` may increase the performance (but may decrease too).